# Primefaces 10 download problem with ajax = "true"

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am having an issue since i switched to primefaces 10 (yes, i have read a migration guide). I know that primefaces 10 does not need ajax = "false" anymore when downloading. When i deleted ajax = "false", it prompted me with a download, with correct filename. The problem is, the content is wrong. The content of a file is always my index page

```
      <p:menuButton id="#{dataTableId}export" value="export" update="messages" rendered="#{controller.displayExportActions}">
         <c:forEach var="action" items="#{controller.exportActions}">
            <p:menuitem value="#{msg[action.getTitle()]}" disabled="#{!action.available}">
               <p:fileDownload value="#{controller.execute(action)}" />
            </p:menuitem>
         </c:forEach>
      </p:menuButton>
```

and here is my java code

```
 DataExportResponse response = action.execute();
         InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getContent());
         return new DefaultStreamedContent().builder().contentType(response.getType()).name(response.getName()).contentEncoding(response.getEncoding()).stream(() -> stream).build();
```

plese note that on java side, everything seems to be fine when looking at debugger. Only when i deleted ajax = "false" from xhtml is when problems start happening.

Comment: Don't use `response.getContent()` as the stream. For an example, check `FileDownloadView.java` https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: The problem is, i fetched that stream from "somewhere else" in application. I can't fetch it from URI. Data in "stream" resource is fine. Is there a way to do that ?