# Primefaces 11 AJAX fileDownload not working fully

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, download

I need a file download that work with `ajax=true` as I specifically need support for `partialSubmit=true`, which only works with ajax requests.

Since PrimeFaces 10, a `fileDownload` should be able to work with `ajax=true`. See the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml?jfwid=8ca9f).

To test this, I added following code

```
<p:commandButton value="Ajax Download" icon="pi pi-arrow-down" ajax="true">
    <p:fileDownload
        value="#{reportService.downloadReviewReportStreamed()}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And the backing bean method:

```
private StreamedContent downloadReviewReportStreamed() {
    return DefaultStreamedContent.builder().name("boromir.jpg")
            .contentType("image/jpg")
            .stream(() -> FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/downloaded_boromir.jpg"))
            .build();
}
```

pretty much according to the showcase. However, when I now click on the button, the download does start, a file is created on my machine, but it is only 1kb in size and can't be openend.

The download does work perfectly fine with `ajax=false`.

I checked the network traffic with chrome developer tools and found that the request URL can't be found.

```
Type Status Report 404

Message /tool/app/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

more specifically:

```
http://localhost:8080/tool/app/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties?ln=primefaces&v=11.0.0&pfdrid=e1359ea2fc7c10f46386d9e582e04753&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=84aac6f4-4da6-42f7-8ca8-4cc8b1527cbc
```

As reference, the request URL from the showcase:

```
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=12.0.0-SNAPSHOT&pfdrid=fd67a30fae4051aa3c28ae2f190094c3&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=0552f7d7-64cc-4231-b9ec-5bf7d78cc338
```

with the difference being `dynamiccontent.properties`(mine) vs `dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml`(theirs). Not sure if this is part of the cause.

**What is causing this error and how can I fix this?**

---

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471200/primefaces-10-download-problem-with-ajax-true) which sounds quite similar, however, the file downloaded in my case is just the error page

Comment: Please create a reproducer https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: I guess the issue is caused by dependencies, as the code works fine in the test project. I will need to test a bit more to find the crux

Comment: I guess it's configuration of your JSF servlet (mapping)

Comment: Hey @XtremeBaumer, I know it's an old post but I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Blockost I don't remember and I am no longer working on that project so can't check