Primefaces Dialog won´t close when same Button includes p:fileDownload
I guess this is a similar problem as described in this question:
Primefaces 11 AJAX fileDownload not working fully
In my case I open a Dialog which, when it is closed, should download a file and then close aftwards.
The file will only be downloaded correctly, when ajax-Attribute of the button is set to "false" and the Dialog won´t close.
If it´s set to true, the Dialog will close, but the downloaded file is corrupt.
I am using Primefaces in Version 13.0.0.
Hope some is able the help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292892/primefaces-11-ajax-filedownload-not-working-fully

[Edit] the question and add the relevant code.

Please report and include a reproducer

Of course it´s working in the reproducer, what makes it somehow difficult for me. I am going to add some more tests (to my Application and Reproducer) and will try to provide more details.

Problem´s gone. Don´t know why exactly. Will tell you, if and when I found out. Thx for your time!
